# How to pass image to API in next.js

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js, file-upload

I am trying to pass API to API endpoint. When I tried to convert file to JSON using `JSON.stringify()` it gave empty object. Then I found some article in which use of `formData` was suggested., but even after using `formData` it still gives empty object.

This is function for `submithandler`:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('title',title)
    formData.append('body',richtext)
    formData.append('file',file)

    console.log(formData)

    const promise = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/setblog", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      // body: JSON.stringify({ titles:title, bodys:richtext, filess:file })
      body:JSON.stringify(formData)
    })

    const response = await promise.json();
    console.log(response);

  };
```

This is `/api/setblog/route.js` file

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
export async function POST(request){

    const data = await request.json();

    console.log(data);
    return NextResponse.json({data})
}
```

I want all the form data in constant data. I was able to get data except image with the commented code present in `submithandler` function above, but with `formData` I was unable to get either of the data. What should I do to get all the data with image? Please help.

PS: Image upload is perfectly working. This is the function to set the file. This function is invoked on `onChange` of file input.

```
const getFile = (e) => {
    const photo = e.target.files[0];
    // console.log(photo)
    setFile(photo);
  };
```